# Using LinearModelFit, how can I test the hypothesis $\beta=c$ with $c\neq 0$?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

Assuming a simple linear model $y=x\beta+u$, is there a way to test the hypothesis $\beta=c$ with $c\neq 0$, using the LinearModelFit?

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but you really should elaborate: you want to test if the slope is equal to a given value?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, you're right. Usually, we would use a wald test for large sample. I don't see that option in Mathematica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways.  Here's one for performing a two-sided test of the slope equaling $c$ by getting the *P*-value:

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}};
lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x];
slopeInfo = lm["ParameterTableEntries"][[2]];
df = lm["ANOVATableDegreesOfFreedom"][[2]];

c = 2;
testStatistic = (slopeInfo[[1]] - c)/slopeInfo[[2]];
pValue = CDF[StudentTDistribution[df], -Abs[testStatistic]] +
  1 - CDF[StudentTDistribution[df], Abs[testStatistic]]
(* 0.0308905 *)
```

A quicker approach is to subtract $c x$ from each $y$ and then test for the resulting slope being zero.

```
data2 = data;
c = 2;
data2[[All, 2]] = data[[All, 2]] - c*data[[All, 1]];
lm = LinearModelFit[data2, x, x];
lm["ANOVATableEntries"][[1, 5]]
(* 0.0308905 *)
```

An even shorter approach uses `LinearOffsetFunction`.

```
c = 2;
lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x, LinearOffsetFunction -> (c*# &)]
lm["ParameterTableEntries"][[2, 4]]
(* 0.0308905 *)
```

But one shouldn't just use a *P*-value to make a decision and, of course, one should only do this when a linear fit is appropriate.

Comment: One could also consider returning a confidence interval instead of a $p$-value. Anyway, for your "quicker approach", one could use an appropriate dot product instead to generate `data2`: `lm = LinearModelFit[data.{{1, -c}, {0, 1}}, x, x]`.

Comment: @J.M. I agree about the confidence intervals.  Those would be much more informative and more direct as one would not have to go through the gyrations to get a P-value for a hypothesis test.  (Although the gyrations are interesting...)  And, thanks, I'll use the dot product next rather than constructing a separate data set.